# Wix - How do I execute process during installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10, wix3.11

During installation, I am required to execute an executable (EXE) given a certain condition.  The execution must be done within a custom action.  The problem is that the custom action is deferred and for some reason the process is not being executed.

I need to call the .EXE with arguments.  The EXE is located in a folder that is always created during installation.  I need to get that path but do not know how to yet.  I am using a hard-coded path for now and storing it in a property.

Calling the executable, it receives an argument that is a path where a file is located that it needs to read.

What am I doing wrong?

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult ExecuteDrugDatabaseSetup(Session session)
{
string databaseName = "ApplicationServer";

try {
    Log(session, "Beginning Drug Database Setup");

    string drugsDBFilePath = session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence).Select(v => v.DrugsDBFilePath).FirstOrDefault();
    string drugsDBLoaderPath = session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence).Select(v => v.DrugsDBLoaderPath).FirstOrDefault();

    Log(session, "drugsDBFilePath = " + drugsDBFilePath);
    Log(session, "drugsDBLoaderPath = " + drugsDBLoaderPath);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drugsDBFilePath)) {
        Log(session, "Have drugs db file path");

        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = drugsDBLoaderPath;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "//DataPackage " + drugsDBFilePath;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    } else {
        Log(session, "No drugs db file path");
        foreach (DatabaseUpdaterSettings settings in session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)) {
            if (settings.DatabaseName == "ApplicationServer") {
                GetUpdater(session, settings).SetupDrugDatabase();
            }
        }
}

return ActionResult.Success;
```

**UPDATE**

I got it to work.  However, now I need to make it run with elevated privileges but without prompting me.  Is there a way to achieve this?

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult ExecuteDrugDatabaseSetup(Session session)
    {
        string databaseName = "ApplicationServer";

        try {
            Log(session, "Beginning Drug Database Setup");

            // TODO: Add a RelativeWeight field to the DatabaseUpdaterSettings so we can specify the relative weights in 
            // the xml. Then add them all up here to get the total ticks for all updates. 
            ResetProgressBar(session, ProgressTicksForAllDatabaseUpdates);

            // Now we will check if we have a Data File path for the DrugsDBLoader to process.  This value was captured
            // at the beginning of the installation. If nothing was entered, we proceed as we have always.  If we have
            // a path, then we just load that specific file.
            string drugsDBFilePath = session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence).Select(v => v.DrugsDBFilePath).FirstOrDefault();
            string drugsDBLoaderPath = session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence).Select(v => v.DrugsDBLoaderPath).FirstOrDefault();

            drugsDBLoaderPath += @"Tools\";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drugsDBFilePath) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(drugsDBFilePath)) {
                Log(session, "Have drugs db file path");

                foreach (DatabaseUpdaterSettings settings in session.CustomActionData.Values.Select(encodedSettings => new DatabaseUpdaterSettings(encodedSettings)).OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)) {
                    if (settings.DatabaseName == "ApplicationServer") {
                        GetUpdater(session, settings).SetProgressTemplates("Drugs DB Setup", "Setting up Drugs Database", "");
                    }
                }

                // It is necessary for the process to RUN AS elevated permissions and we indicate that with the VERB property assigned.
                // Since this is an external process, it must be explicitly elevated; it does not inherit the elevation of the ServerSetup
                FileInfo drugsDBFile = new FileInfo(@drugsDBFilePath);
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
                    FileName = Path.Combine(drugsDBLoaderPath, "DrugsDBLoader.exe"),
                    WorkingDirectory = "\"" + @drugsDBLoaderPath + "\"",
                    Arguments = $"/DataDirectory:\"{drugsDBFile.Directory}\" /DataPackage:{drugsDBFile.Name}",
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    UseShellExecute = true
                    //Verb = "runas"
                };
                Log(session, $"Command: {startInfo.FileName} {startInfo.Arguments}");

                try {
                    using (Process dbLoaderProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
                        dbLoaderProcess.WaitForExit();
                    }
                } catch (Win32Exception ex) {
                    if (ex.NativeErrorCode == 1223) { //The operation was canceled by the user.
                        Log(session, "User chose not to proceed with DrugsDBLoader");
                    } else {
                        Log(session, ex.Message);
                    }
                    ShowError(session, "Failed to update {0}: {1}. Create / examine installation log for details.", databaseName, ex.GetBaseException().Message.TrimEnd('.'));
                    return ActionResult.Failure;
                }
            } else {
                // some code here
            }
```

Comment: One question first: do you have or can you obtain the source code for the EXE in question? It is very clunky to rely on EXE calls in an MSI, it would be much better to call it as a dll function.

Comment: Why can't it be a deferred action or even a post-install launch?

Comment: This is a deferred action, but I do not have the source code available.